# how to replace a key in dict python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
d={"given_age":"30","given_weight":"160","given_height":6}
```

want to remove `"given_"` from each of the key,

```
for key,value in d.items():
      new_key=re.sub(r'given_','',key)
      if new_key!=key:
            d[new_key]=d.pop(key)
```

getting below error, my intention is to change the key only, why does it complain?

```
RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration
```

Comment: in fact you are appending new pair of key:value instead of changing existing pair, _how you thinking i guess_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is best not to modify collections when iterating over them. Use a dict comprehension here instead.

```py
res = {re.sub('given_','',k) : v for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: so, you are creating a new dict here, right?

Comment: @user2333234 Yes, that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `str.replace()` with dict comprehensiomn

```
d={"given_age":"30","given_weight":"160","given_height":6}

{key.replace('given_', '') : value for key, value in d.items()}

#{'age': '30', 'weight': '160', 'height': 6}
```

Edit as suggested by @CrazyChucky

```
{key.removeprefix('given_') : value for key, value in d.items()}
#{'age': '30', 'weight': '160', 'height': 6}
```

Comment: Or `str.removeprefix`

Comment: yes you are right !

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this "in-place" and only change the keys that have the "given_" prefix, you could use the update method:

```
d.update((k[6:],d.pop(k)) for k in d if k.startswith("given_"))
```